# Constructing a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am looking to construct a sequence of measurable sets such that $A_k \subset R $ such that $limsupA_k = R$ but $\lambda(A_k)=1$ ( Note where $\lambda(A_k)$ stands for measure of $A_K$) for all k .

I am trying to come up with such a sequence to prove that the reverse fatou lemma can't hold without additional assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to construct sets $A_k$ with $\lambda(A_k)=1$ such that every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ belongs to infinitely many $A_k$.

Let $B_{2n}=[n,n+1]$ and $B_{2n+1}=[-n-1,-n]$. Now, arrange the $B_k$'s in a grid, like this

$$\begin{array}{cccccc}
B_0&B_0&B_0&\dots&B_0&\dots\\
B_1&B_1&B_1&\dots&B_1&\dots\\
B_2&B_2&B_2&\dots&B_2&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\dots\\
B_k&B_k&B_k&\dots&B_k&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\dots\\
\end{array}$$

And assign $A_k$ to the corresponding $B_n$ you're on as you traverse this grid in a zig zag pattern, like in the following image:

[image]

Comment: So here what goes in the sequence of sets $A_k$ , I am guessing $A_1$ , but what does $A_1$ contain ?

I am not quite clear about your construction , what are $B_{2n}$  and $B_k$?

Comment: How is the measure of the sets that you are constructing equal to 1 ?

Comment: Each set is an interval of length $1$. If $k=2n$, $B_k$ is the interval $[n,n+1]$. If $k=2n+1$, $B_k$ is the interval $[-n-1,-n]$. In the scheme above, $A_1=A_2=B_0$, $A_3=B_1$, $A_4=B_0$, $A_5=B_1$ and $A_6=B_2$. The process goes on.